# MVC Route Weirdness

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-mvc-areas

Hey all, brand new to asp.net mvc and I am creating a fake social site (for learning purposes) by building off the stock mvc template... I added some views, etc. which all work fine.  However, now I have added an mvc area called "Blog" and added the link to the main menu. Now if I click on any of the menu items, things work as expected - however when I click on the "Blog" menu item the view, etc show the blog page however the menus links for the other views have the /Blog/ in front of the URL now!? Not sure if I'm doing something wrong... here is my menu code:

```
<div id="menucontainer">
                <ul id="menu">
                    @* @Html.ActionLink() Params = String Name, String Controller Name,
                    string Method (actionLink) Name *@
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Mail", "Index", "Mail")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Search", "Index", "Search")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Dating", "Index", "Dating")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Groups", "Index", "Groups")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Forums", "Index", "Board")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Blog", "Index", "Blog")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

Comment: @BJSafdie: I think the question clearly mentions areas

Comment: Duh, yeah. Sorry the lower case threw me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If Blog is in a separate Area from the others, MVC expects links from that area to be within the same Area, so it appends the Area to your URL.  If they are in a different Area, you need to invoke ActionLink with an "Area" route value. For instance, if "Dating" is in the "Social" area, you might use:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Dating", "Index", new { controller = "Dating", area = "Social" } );
```

Here is the relevant discussion from [What’s New in ASP.NET MVC 2](http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/what-is-new-in-aspnet-mvc):

> **“Area” is a now a reserved route-value key**
>
> The string “area” in Route values now
>   has special meaning in ASP.NET MVC, in
>   the same way that “controller” and
>   “action” do. One implication is that
>   if HTML helpers are supplied with a
>   route-value dictionary containing
>   “area”, the helpers will no longer
>   append “area” in the query string.
>
> If you are using the Areas feature,
>   make sure to not use {area} as part of
>   your route URL.

Comment: Use this concept to make an extension methods for HtmlHelper for the incarnations of ActionLink you most commonly use. It will save you lots of keystrokes and frustration later.

Comment: @Chad, not entirely sure what you mean here?  I have read a bit about HtmlHelpers but not sure how that would help with the ActionLink part of the Controller?

Comment: Thx a ton BJ! Got everything running, a bit confusing - never ready anything on that from my google searches... glad I posted. Only question is... who do I award the answer to!? Should I post another question about it!? Lol

Answer (score 1):

It takes undefined values from current context. For example `@Html.ActionLink("Test", "Test")` will create link relative to controller. So for example if you will render this on `Foo` controller it will render element `<a href="/Foo/Test">Test</a>`. Same goes for area - if you want static link across areas, you will have to define to which area it should guide you. Example: `@Html.ActionLink("Test", "Test", "Foo", new { @area = string.Empty }, null)` will always link to controller `Foo` action `Test` with no area.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, you gave the part of the equation I couldn't figure out after BJ suggested how to setup the rest of the formula... empty @area equals the Home or default route I suppose.  Thanks guys, cleared it up! Would have been stuck on this one for a while... was thinking of routes like url rewrites....